# Is it possible to use Laravel components in a WordPress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, laravel

I need to write a rather complex plugin for WordPress and I would like to use the Laravel framework components for a lot of the grunt work.  Is it possible to use the Laravel components without using the whole Laravel framework?

I'm particularly interested in using its ORM.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can. because

> Laravel 4 uses Composer for dependency management as the framework
>   itself depends on a number of external packages to function correctly.
>   Each of the components used by Laravel 4 is available individually on
>   the [Illuminate](http://github.com/illuminate) GitHub repository. Laravel 4 ties together the
>   Illuminate components to create the framework.

So, for example, if you want to use [Illuminate Database](https://github.com/illuminate/database) component you have to create a new "Capsule" manager instance. Capsule aims to make configuring the library for usage outside of the Laravel framework as easy as possible.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
]);
```

Once the Capsule instance has been registered. You may use it like so:
(Using The Query Builder)

```
$users = Capsule::table('users')->where('votes', '>', 100)->get();
```

For full component list [visit this link](https://github.com/illuminate). Also, you can find details about a component on [Laravel site](http://laravel.com/docs).

**Update :**
Also make sure that you have these in your server because `Laravel-4` requires these.

```
PHP >= 5.3.7
MCrypt PHP Extension
```

You can also take a look at [Symfony Components](http://symfony.com/components), `Laravel` itself uses these components in it's core components.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  Just as a note, you seem to have to assign $capsule to the Manager's global static instance variable before you can call Capsule::table() or Capsule::connection()  

`$capsule->setAsGlobal();`

Answer (score 2):

The framework code for laravel is available at https://github.com/laravel/framework. Taylor has made each component of laravel available for use at https://github.com/illuminate. So if you're interested in eloquent, check out https://github.com/illuminate/database. The readme has usage instructions.

Also, here's a link to a tutorial for Slim Framework that implemented eloquent as a standalone package: http://www.slimframework.com/news/slim-and-laravel-eloquent-orm